# Cannot sort array of object by property name

Tags: php

I have this array:

```
$array = array(
    ['name' => 'Indor Swimming Pool'],
    ['name' => 'abracadabra'],
);
```

I want sort if alphabetically, so I did:

```
usort($array, function($a, $b)
{
    return strcmp($a['name'], $b['name']);
});
```

but when I dump it:

```
var_dump($array);
```

I get:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(19) "Indor Swimming Pool"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(11) "abracadabra"
  }
}
```

this is incorrect, `abracadabra` should go as first

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Sort Multi-dimensional Array by Value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/how-to-sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value)

Comment: @Legeekthe_dev unfortunately not, the array is not sorted alphabetically

Comment: The result you are getting _is_ correct, for the _case sensitive_ comparison you are doing here. If you want a case insensitive comparison - then use `strcasecmp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the ASCII table chr **I** comes first and then comes the **a** chr

[ASCII Table](http://www.asciitable.com/)

So here your array is actually getting sorted alphabetically to achieve the desired result you need to sort the array in the descending order

```
<?php
$data = array(
    ['name' => 'Indor Swimming Pool'],
    ['name' => 'abracadabra'],
);
arsort($data);
?>
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => abracadabra
        )

    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Indor Swimming Pool
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

It works as intended. The reason for this order is that 'a' is actually after 'I' in ASCII.